# How to redirect yyout to char* buffer in GNU flex?

Tags: c, gnu, flex-lexer

By default `yyout` is set to `stdout` and can be redirected to `FILE*` stream. Is a way to redirect `yyout` to `char*`?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do it. Can you post a bit of your scanner code where you are trying to use yyout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it. If you post a bit of your scanner code where you are trying to use yyout may be I can give you a more specific answer:

Typically it's in your action where you'd do this. So instead of using `ECHO` or `fprintf(yyout...` you'd use something else like

```
<token>  { snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s", yytext); }
```

earlier you'd have declared:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
```

## addendum I - An alternate approach

There are clever ways of dealing with the situation, but they are prone to maintenance problems in the long run because they are "clever" .. .and the cleverer a solution the shorter its life. (unless the cleverness is well documented with caveats attached)

```
 int yyprintf(const char *fmt, ...)  {
     va_list ap;
     va_start(ap, fmt);
     if ( some_flag & FLAG_OUTFILE ) {
         vfprintf(yyout, fmt, ap);
     }
     else {
         sprintf(buf, fmt, ap);
     }
     va_end(ap);
 }
```

where buf is a global buffer.

However if you want to make things a bit local:

### Approach 2: Fine-grain control over where things go and when

You want fine grain control over where things go along the way. Sometimes you want output
to file, other times to a string, and you don't always know which is which and when and where you can use something like this:

```
 int myvprintf(void *here, size_t len, const char *fmt, va_list ap) 
      __attribute__((format (gnu_printf, 3, 4), nonnull(1, 3))) {
     
     int rv;

     if ( len > 0 ) { 
        rv = vsnprintf((char *), len, fmt, ap);
     }
     else {
        rv = vfprintf((FILE *)here, fmt, ap);
     }

     return rv;
 }

 int myprintf(void *here, size_t len, const char *fmt, ... ) 
      __attribute__((format (gnu_printf, 3, 4), nonnull(1, 3))) {
     int rv;
     va_list ap;
     va_start(ap, fmt);
     rv = myvprintf(here, len, fmt, ap);
     va_end(ap);
     return rv;
 }
```

and use myprintf along the way, you will have control over what is `here` all the time.

### Just for Fun

Don't try this at home. But all yy* identifiers and ECHO are not plain variables, they are #define's. So you could do some clever macro rewriting:

For example, if you are using ECHO everywhere then you can redefine it to do whatever you like (just #undef and #define) in the top section:

```
%{
#undef ECHO
#define ECHO snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s", yytext)
%}

%%

<token> ECHO;
%%
```

just hide it all in convoluted headers and do other cleverness that will make debugging a hell later for a programmer you hate. This can have its own rewards and giggles.

Comment: Ahmed, thanks a lot for your attention. I’d like to redirect 'yyout' in the same way as described in documentation about redirection of 'yyint'. When we call function 'yy_scan_string ( const char *str )' 'yyin' switches to 'const char *str' instead of 'FILE* stdin'. I’d like to call some function (similar to 'yy_scan_string', but for 'yyout') that pointed 'yyout' to 'char *buffer' instead of 'FILE *stdout'. Your answer is really helpful for me, but it required some work for every token in already working scanner.

Comment: Hi Alex: ugh you should've said something about that... I would've come up with a cleverer way :) I am sorry that I put this answer in (it was very late last night and I wasn't thinking all that clearly) and made you work would you hate me if I gave an alternate?

Comment: Hi, Ahmed! Thanks a lot! It seems that the second approach will let me to modify my scanner with the smallest efforts. I’ll try it after weekend.